if + were/are in conditional

#1 if you are tired tomorrow, you won't have had enough sleep


#2 if you were tired tomorrow, you won't have had enough sleep

I know the difference, but can I use #2 in daily life? and is it grammatically wrong to use #2?

The second doesn't make sense.
It seems to be a "counterfactual" or "third conditional". It means "You were not tired tomorrow, but let's imagine that you were".
But you can't make counterfactuals about the future (unless you have a time machine). That's why the third conditional uses past and past-perfect.
So the second is not possible in sensible English.
